# Extract Regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, date, extract

As I can do to remove this type of dates from a string in PHP

`En progreso Sin resolver 14/jul/16 17/jul/16 19/jul/16 12:00 PM 12 h   Acciones`

I want to extract only this: `19/jul/16 12:00 PM`

Comment: I want to extract the date and put it in an array

Comment: Is this sentence format is fixed ? if yes why not explode by single space ?

Comment: Will this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nB3wJ3/5) do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
$pattern = '#\d{1,2}/\w+/\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s[AP]M#';
$string = ' df progreso sin resolver 14/jul/16 17/jul/16 19/jul/16 12:00 PM 12 h   Acciones';

preg_match($pattern , $string , $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

result will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 19/jul/16 12:00 PM
)
```

Comment: If you change delimiter `/` to any other, for example `#`, `~`, `@`, etc.; then you don't need to escape `/` in pattern. This leads to better readability and shorter pattern.

Comment: perfect, amazing, I thought it was not going to be able to do

Answer (score -1):

If this is a static string, this code will work for you:

```
$string = "En progreso Sin resolver 14/jul/16 17/jul/16 19/jul/16 12:00 PM 12 h Acciones";
$array  = explode(' ', $string);
echo implode(' ',[$array[6], $array[7], $array[8]]);
```

**Output:**

```
19/jul/16 12:00 PM
```

Comment: This breaks if string has one more/less word.